# Infinispan remote lazy locking

Tags: java, jboss6.x, infinispan

We are using Infinispan 4.0 as our caching provider ( i know it's kind of antique as version 9 is the latest ). That being said , i am a little bit confused while reading the documentation that states :

> Infinispan, by default, acquires remote locks lazily. Locks are acquired locally on a node that runs a transaction while other cluster nodes attempt to lock cache keys involved in a transaction during two-phase prepare/commit phase. However, if desired, Infinispan can eagerly lock cache keys either explicitly or implicitly.

What is the default behavior of Infinispan ? I understand that it locks only on the local node but exactly when does it lock on the cluster ? For example if you have an operation like :

```
Cache.put(K,V)
```

How does it behave when another node in the cluster attempts a concurrent

```
Cache.put(K,V)
```

operation? How does this remote lazy locking work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comment was about transactions. With transactions, the remote locks could be acquired either during `cache.put(k, v)` (eager) or during `tm.commit()` (lazy). Without transactions, there's no distinction between the two.

Note that the locking in 4.x was very prone to deadlocks. A node would acquire the local lock, then it would try to acquire the locks on all the other owners, and there was a high chance of a deadlock if another node tried to write to the same key concurrently.

Comment: Ok got it . Thank you for the note about the deadlocks